# Как добавить обрабочик нескольких кнопок в моем приложением WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть приложение в стиле неоморфизм. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на кнопку она как-будто впадала, но при этом, если нажать на другую кнопку, то кнопка, которая была нажата до этого, вернулась в первоначальное положение. Также нужно сделать `Click` у `Border`. Я начал изучать WPF относительно недавно, поэтому пока не знаю всех тонкостей. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Сам код:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="#E0E5EC">
        <Border Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SurroundingBorder"
                Height="100" Width="100" Cursor="Hand"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#E0E5EC"
                BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="12">
            <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" Background="#E0E5EC">
                <Border x:Name="InnerLowerBorder"
                        Height="100" Width="100" Cursor="Hand"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#E0E5EC"
                        BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="12">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="InnerDarkShadow" BlurRadius="12"
                                          ShadowDepth="5" Direction="315"
                                          Color="#000000" Opacity="0.2"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="InnerUpperBorder" 
                        Height="100" Width="100" Cursor="Hand"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#E0E5EC"
                        BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="12">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="InnerLightShadow" BlurRadius="12"
                                          ShadowDepth="5" Direction="135"
                                          Color="#FFFFFF" Opacity="0.8"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Grid Name="OuterGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <Border x:Name="OuterLowerBorder"
                    Height="90" Width="90" Cursor="Hand"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="#E0E5EC" BorderBrush="#E0E5EC"
                    BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="7">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="OuterDarkShadow" BlurRadius="12"
                                      ShadowDepth="5" Direction="315"
                                      Color="#000000" Opacity="0.2"/>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="OuterUpperBorder"
                    Height="90" Width="90" Cursor="Hand"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="#E0E5EC" BorderBrush="#E0E5EC"
                    BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="7">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="OuterLightShadow" BlurRadius="12"
                                      ShadowDepth="5" Direction="135"
                                      Color="#FFFFFF" Opacity="0.8"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <Border.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>

                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterGrid"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterUpperBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="90" To="80" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" >
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterUpperBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     From="90" To="80" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" >
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterLowerBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="90" To="80" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" >
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterLowerBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     From="90" To="80" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" >
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterDarkShadow"     
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"
                                     From="5" To="0" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterLightShadow"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"     
                                     From="5" To="0" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDarkShadow"     
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"
                                     From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerLightShadow"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"     
                                     From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterGrid"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterUpperBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="90" To="100" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterUpperBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     From="90" To="100" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterLowerBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="90" To="100" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterLowerBorder"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     From="90" To="100" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterDarkShadow"     
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"
                                     From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterLightShadow"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"     
                                     From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDarkShadow"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"     
                                     From="5" To="0" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerLightShadow"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"     
                                     From="5" To="0" Duration="0:0:0:0.2">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Border.Triggers>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Когда кликаешь на кнопку, нужно прописать в этой функции кнопка2.isClicked = false. А цвет (типо кнопка впала) можно менять тоже в функциях кнопка_cliked, которые автоматически создаются при двойном клике на кнопку в дизайнере

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно, чтобы `ToggleButton` вёл себя как `RadioButton`. Для этого проще всего использовать следующий трюк: положить набор `RadioButton`'ов, но стилизовать их так, чтобы они выглядели как `ToggleButton`'ы.

Пример:

```xml
<StackPanel Margin="5,0">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton Margin="0,5,0,0">1</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Margin="0,5,0,0">2</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Margin="0,5,0,0">3</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

даёт следующий UI:

[image: ну да, хак, но семантичный]

---

Разоблачение магии: стиль «по умолчанию» для всякого типа контролов доступен по ключу, равному типу этого контрола. Поэтому `{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}` даёт стиль по умолчанию для `ToggleButton`, а он содержит, конечно, и шаблон. Вы можете дальше кастомизировать стиль, дописав что-нибудь внутри:

```xml
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <!-- здесь, конечно -->
</Style>
```