# Нажатие кнопок с анимацией WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть анимация у нескольких кнопок. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на одну кнопку анимация всех остальных возвращалась в исходное положение. Анимацию описываю непосредственно в C#, а не в XAML.

```
private void Task_LeftClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation TaskAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
            TaskAnimation1.From = FirstTask.ActualWidth;
            TaskAnimation1.To = 130;
            TaskAnimation1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            DoubleAnimation TaskAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();
            TaskAnimation2.From = SecondTask.ActualWidth;
            TaskAnimation2.To = 130;
            TaskAnimation2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            FirstTask.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, TaskAnimation1);
            SecondTask.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, TaskAnimation2);
        }
        private void Profile_LeftClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            DoubleAnimation TaskAnimation3 = new DoubleAnimation();
            TaskAnimation3.From = FirstProfile.ActualWidth;
            TaskAnimation3.To = 130;
            TaskAnimation3.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            DoubleAnimation TaskAnimation4 = new DoubleAnimation();
            TaskAnimation4.From = SecondProfile.ActualWidth;
            TaskAnimation4.To = 130;
            TaskAnimation4.AutoReverse = true;
            TaskAnimation4.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            FirstProfile.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, TaskAnimation3);
            SecondProfile.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, TaskAnimation4);
        }
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода - какие анимации есть, как описываете.

Comment: `Анимацию описываю непосредственно в C#, а не в XAML.` - плохо! `Как мне сделать так, чтобы анимация всех остальных возвращалась в исходное положение` - наверно задать эти исходные значения нужным свойствам (ну или запустить аналогичную анимацию, где `To` будет равно стандартному значению).

Comment: _Анимацию описываю непосредственно в C#, а не в XAML._ - что только люди не придумают, лишь бы не изучать технологии. Я бы помог, но я умею только в XAML.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить обрабочик нескольких кнопок в моем приложением WPF?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1224240/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-wpf)